# How to user input using "cin" while using composition in C++

Tags: c++, composition

I have three C++ class, InventoryItem, SalesPerson and Transaction. I am using composition to use InventoryItem and SalesPerson class in Transaction. I want to use user input instead of just passing values in constructor, but I am not being able to do it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Following is my C++ file.

```
    #include<iostream> 
    #include<string> 
    using namespace std; 

    class InventoryItem {
    private:
        int stockNum; double price;
    public:
        InventoryItem(int, double);
        void display(); };
    InventoryItem::InventoryItem(int stkNum, double pr) {
        stockNum = stkNum;
        price = pr; 
    }
    void InventoryItem::display() {
        cout << "Item #" << stockNum << " costs $" << price << endl;
    }

    //SalesPerson class
    class Salesperson {
    private:
        int idNum;
        string name; public:
        Salesperson(int, string); void display();
    };
    Salesperson::Salesperson(int id, string lastName) {
        idNum = id;
        name = lastName; 
    }
    void Salesperson::display() {
        cout << "Salesperson #" << idNum << " " << name << endl;
    }

    //Transaction(main class)
    class Transaction {
    private:
        int transNum; 
        InventoryItem itemSold; 
        Salesperson seller;
    public:
        Transaction(int, int, double, int, string); 
        void display();
    };
    Transaction::Transaction(int num, int item, double pr,
                             int salesId, string name) : itemSold(item, pr),
        seller(salesId, name) {
        transNum = num; 
    }
    void Transaction::display() {
        cout << "Data for transaction #" << transNum << endl; itemSold.display();
        seller.display();
    }
    int main() {
        Transaction aSale(247, 782, 44.77, 512, "Richardson"); aSale.display();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with passing parameters to constructors. That is the way you *should* be doing it. User input should be handled separately. This makes the code reusable and testable when input types change (ie, user input vs files vs mocks).

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer instead of comment, because i dont have backticks on my phone. So you want to do something like

```
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    double f;
    string name;

    cin >> x >> y >> f >> z >> name;

    Transaction(x, y, f, z, name);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can divide the `cin` line into one `cin` per variable and `cout` instructions on what a user must input next. This would look like this

```
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    double f;
    string name;

    cout << "Enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter y: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter f: ";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Enter z: ";
    cin >> z;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;

    Transaction(x, y, f, z, name);
    return 0;
}
```

Substitute strings in `cout` lines with strings you want to prompt the user with.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. How can I put output label for each of these input fields. Eg, cout<<"Enter first Num";"Second Num" etc